# Python3.5/http/client.py SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I am a beginner in python. Unfortunately, I just deleted the:

```
    ..Python3.5/http/
```

directory.

To fix that, I downloaded the same from 
        https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/http

But when I run any script that needs the content of the deleted folder, I get this error

```
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1063
        chunk = f"{len(chunk):X}\r\n".encode('ascii') + chunk \
                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the syntax error and how can I fix this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: f-strings are new in Python 3.6. You try to run Python 3.6 code with Python 3.5.

Comment: Try https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.5/Lib/http, or just reinstall it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that is throwing the error is using the new 'f-string' syntax [introduced in Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498). You are trying to run it with Python 3.5 which does not support this feature.

To fix this you could either redownload the files from [3.5 branch](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.5/Lib/http) or just reinstall Python using the installer.